# Flex save file dialog for URL

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flex4.5, savefiledialog

I will have a list of links to PDF documents in my Flex web app.

What I want to do is that upon clicking some button, open SAVE AS dialog for some pdf from the URL list and download it to disk.

What I want to avoid is viewing PDF in browser.

ALL I know is that `flash.net.FileReference` will take raw data but no links. So is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use to get raw data from url by URLStream's load method. Save it as ByteArray and later use FileReference.save() method to save files to local system(starting from flash player 10).

For more information you can see at:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

Comment: used `download` method instead